# ETL options with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, etl

Currently we warehouse our postgres db using SSIS, but there are certain things we can't do, for example with an ADO.Net provider it isn't possible to use parameters in a data source of the data flow component, we're trying out an OLEDB provider PGNP which looks like it does what we require.

I'd like to know what other options are available and your opinions of them. I've used open talend, but the performance wasn't that good compared to SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Pentaho Data Integration (PDI, formerly, kettle).

Community Edition is free.

It has a GUI similar to SSIS, easy to use after a short introduction.

It is a Java application, and it uses original, native postgresql JDBC driver - performance should be at least comparable to SSIS.

PDI CE download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/

Comment: I tried it, but it wasn't as flexible for me. Pretty good for simpler tasks though.

Answer (score 2):

We ended up using [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com/). Does what it says on the tin:

> CloverETL® is data integration platform scaling from open source desktop to a commercial cloud cluster.
>   It's a Java-based open platform that helps design, automate, and monitor data integration processes.